# Package "@twilio-conversations" does not compile in typescript

Tags: typescript, twilio, twilio-conversations

I am trying to run the package `@twilio-conversations` in react-typescript.

It fails to compile with following error:

```
./src/components/communications/conversations/ConversationsSetup.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve '@twilio-conversations' in ...
```

Declaring the module in definition file: `@types/alltypes.d.ts` -> [`declare module "@twilio-conversations"`] does not help.

With JavaScript it works fine.

Can anyone let me know, if they are facing similar issue?

Comment: I'm just guessing, but did you try adding `"@twilio-conversations"` to your tsconfig.js under `"types"` ?

Comment: In file: `tsconfig.json`, I have added: "typeRoots": [
    "./node_modules/@types",
    "./@types"
  ]
And in the file: `@Types/alltypes.d.ts` -> I have added: `declare module "@twilio-conversations"`

Note: Other packages like `react-stopwatch`, `react-stepper-horizontal` work with the above approach, but this package: `@twilio-conversations` is not working with same approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to package with name: `@twilio/conversations` started working.